# ToolbarManager not focusable

Tags: blackberry

I have an application where I have a toolbarmanager on the bottom of the screen to control which screen is shown. The toolbar works great for touch but it is not focusable. I tried creating it with focusable style but no luck.

So far I tried:
tbm=new ToolbarManager(Manager.FOCUSABLE);

Additional details:

Now when I try to add FOCUSABLE to the ToolbarButtonField the whole toolbar disappears. Not sure why that is happening.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't set a focus to a manager, you'll have to set the focus for the fields inside it. Now for the ToolbarManager, you can use the ToolbarButtonField and set him to focus, so the manager will get focused.

You can solve it by using the following.

```
    ToolbarManager mana = new ToolbarManager();
    ToolbarButtonField test = new ToolbarButtonField(){
        public boolean isFocusable() {
            return true;
        }

        protected void onFocus(int direction) {
            super.onFocus(direction);
            invalidate();
        }

        protected void onUnfocus() {
            super.onUnfocus();
            invalidate();
        }
    };
    test.setText(new StringProvider("AAAA"));
    mana.add(test);
    add(mana);
```

Comment: Have you ever done this? I get null pointer exceptions when I tried it.

Comment: Didn't work with Toolbar Manager but worked with managers. When adding this, do you have in the manager a focusable field? or not?

Comment: @BrianG Check the updated post. I tried it now and it works like this. If you need more help tell me